Quick measure not working in Power BI Desktop, version april 2024
I am working on the new April 2024 version of Power BI. I need to use a quick measure (mathematical operations > percentage difference). Unfortunately, every time I try to use this quick measure, my Power BI crashes.
I tried another quick measure (aggregate by category > average by category) and it seems to be working fine. Are there any bugs with the new version? Because some quick measures are not working for me :( If not, what could be the problem? I want to do a simple calculation: Actual_Duration[Actual_Duration - Projects_plans[Planned_Duration]) / Projects_plans[Planned_Duration]) * 100. How can I write this in DAX in a new measure, if the quick measure does not work?"

Posts on Stack Overflow have to be in English. Dual-language posts aren't allowed either, so I've removed the French parts. Please leave those out in the future.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

maybe you can try to re-install the powerbi. Usually we seldom use quick measure. What about create a measure by typing DAX?
